# Computing definite 2d sine integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

For $t>0$ consider the integral
$$F(t):=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\frac{1-x y}{ \sqrt{1-x^2} \sqrt{1-y^2}
   }\Bigl(\frac{\sin\left(t(x-y)\right)}{x-y}\Bigr)^2 \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y.$$
Is this a known integral? Mathematica is unable to compute it symbolically even for $t=1$.

However numerically it seems that $F(t)\approx 0.636 \lvert t\rvert$ but I am not sure whether this is exact or only approximate.

If $F(t)$ cannot be expressed elementarily (or via some known special functions) I would be interested in the large $t$ asympototics of $F(t)$.

**Edit:**

By differentiating twice I managed to find a formula using Mathematica,
$$F(t)=t^2 {_2F_3}(1/2,1/2;1,3/2,2;-4t^2) - 
 \frac{t^4}{6} {_2F_3}(3/2, 3/2; 5/2, 3, 3; -4 t^2),$$
where $F$ is the generalised hypergeometric function. In particular for large $t$, it follows that $F(t)\sim 2t/\pi$.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent No, actually not so sure :) I corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your edit, I computed (with quite many trouble) the value of $F(t)$ for integer values $1 \leq t \leq 50$.

A first quick and dirty linear regression gave $(R^2>0.999999)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -0.004428 & 0.001355 & \{-0.007161,-0.001695\} \\
 b & +0.636726 & 0.000045 & \{+0.636635,+0.636818\} \\
\end{array}$$

Removing the intercept
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 b & +0.636597 & 0.00002 & \{+0.636547,+0.636647\} \\
\end{array}$$

So $b \sim \frac 2 \pi$.

Now, after you nice formula
$$F(t)=t^2 \, _2F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,\frac{3}{2},2;-4 t^2\right)-\frac{1}{6}
   t^4 \, _2F_3\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{2},3,3;-4 t^2\right)$$ its expansion for large values of $t$ is
$$F(t)=\frac 2 \pi t-\frac{2 \sin (4 t)+1}{16 \pi t}+\frac{3 \cos (4 t)}{64 \pi t^2}+\frac{3 (11 \sin (4 t)+1)}{1024 \pi t^3}-\frac{255 \cos (4 t)}{8192 \pi t^4}$$ $$-\frac{45 (223 \sin (4 t)+8)}{262144 \pi t^5}+\frac{119385 \cos (4 t)}{2097152 \pi t^6}+\frac{9808785 \sin (4 t)}{134217728 \pi t^7}-\frac{163426725 \cos (4 t)}{1073741824 \pi t^8}+\cdots$$

For $t=50$, this trucated expansion gives
$$F(50)=31.8312885216715079$$ while the exact value is
$$F(50)=31.8312885216715035$$